# Can't go forward after going back to question list when using custom tabs

Tags: bug, new-nav

Here's the steps to repro:

1. Have a custom tab in the [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav) with several tags in it (I'm doing it with 10 tags)
2. Navigate to a question from the displayed list
3. Look at the question, decide you're not interested just yet so use the browser "back" button to go back to the question list.
4. When back on the list change your mind and now you want to look at the question again so press the browser "forward" button but notice that it's greyed out.

It seems that when going back to the question list, there's some sort of cleverness that is messing with the navigation history.

I've tested in Chrome and Edge and get the same result.

Comment: This might be related to the page view state; when you edit a question and save, navigate away, and then hit back, it takes you back to the previous page, but in a pre-edit state.

Comment: @TylerH No, I don't do anything on the question page, just read it and go back. I can see the forward button is enabled, but there's some funky Ajax style stuff going on to refresh the question and featured-on-meta sidebox, after that the ability to go forward is gone.

Comment: Happens in Pale Moon (Firefox fork) too.

Comment: @hjpotter92 This has nothing to do with [meta-tag:navigation-arrows], it's the browser back & forward button.