# Navigating 'Back' from question changes my custom tab settings

Tags: bug, new-nav

It's similar to [Can't go forward after going back to question list when using custom tabs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311440/cant-go-forward-after-going-back-to-question-list-when-using-custom-tabs) where I have a customized tab like this:
[image]

But when I open a question, decide that it's not interesting and click on the back button of chrome, the tab looks like this:
[image]

The filter is set to `all` and order by to `newest` in both cases.
To resolve the problem, I have to navigate to any other tab and then to the "Tableau" one.

Comment: Ah, so the back button is even more broken on the new nav.  It has a history of problems, as seen by these [back button problems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=back+button+%5Bnew-nav%5D)